# Data type error with drawContours unless I pickle/unpickle first

Tags: python, opencv

I'm running into an interesting error with opencv 2.4.3 on python 2.7.3 on Windows.  When attempting to use drawContours I get a "TypeError: contours data type = 5 is not supported" error unless I pickle/unpickle the contours first.

This doesn't work (I get the "TypeError: contours data type = 5 is not supported"):

```
noBg = cv2.blur(src, (5,5))
noBg = cv2.inRange(noBg, np.array([80, 0, 200], np.uint8), np.array([255, 50, 255], np.uint8)) 
noBg = np.invert(noBg)
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(noBg, cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cv2.drawContours(src, contours, -1, (0,255,0), 3)
```

But this does work:

```
noBg = cv2.blur(src, (5,5))
noBg = cv2.inRange(noBg, np.array([80, 0, 200], np.uint8), np.array([255, 50, 255], np.uint8)) 
noBg = np.invert(noBg)
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(noBg, cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

tmp = cPickle.dumps(contours)    
contours = cPickle.loads(tmp)

cv2.drawContours(src, contours, -1, (0,255,0), 3)
```

Has anyone else seen this behavior or am I missing something obvious?  I'm new to python/opencv so that may very well be the case.

**Edit:** Just tested this on my Mac, and both cases work fine. Maybe just a Windows problem?

Comment: Have you checked if the pickle process actually ends up changing your contours data type?  You should write some more code to test how pickle/unpickle actually modifies the data.

Comment: If I use print, the data looks the same before and after pickling.  Is there a better way for me to compare the two?  I agree that something has to be different.

Comment: @user1816939 I really have no idea how you'd do a better comparison.  Perhaps by going through and just printing out the value of all the objects' members?  Although that would involve writing more code than it should...  Perhaps some sort of debugger can do it?

Comment: `cv2.contourArea()` has the same bug

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you downgrade to opencv 2.4.2 this will work.  It appears to be a bug with 2.4.3 which was just released two weeks ago.

Answer (score 4):

I have just experienced the same problem after getting OpenCV 2.4.3 when using contours from findContours and convexHull. As I did not want to downgrade, casting the contours array elements to int temporarily solves the problem.

```
contours, _ = cv2.findContours(noBg,cv2.RETR_LIST ,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE,offset = (0,0))
hull_contour = cv2.convexHull(contours[0].astype('int'))
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with drawing polylines. It expected 32 bit integers.

I was casting the points to uint32:

```
use_points = np.uint32(original_points)
```

The problem was that it was expecting signed integers of 32 bits, not unsigned integers. It was a subtelty in the code so it was hard to find, but then this worked:

```
use_points = np.int32(original_points)
```

Just using `np.int32` instead of `np.uint32`